# Need help with this proof by induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction

I don't understand a step in the following proof by induction.
I have to prove that:
$$A(n):\quad2^n>n+1$$
By induction:

The base clause is given by $n=2$, which yields $2^2=4$ and $2+1=3$, which is true because $4>3$.
The proof starts as follows:
$$2^{k+1}=2\cdot 2^k.$$
Due to
$$A(n):\quad2^n>n+1$$
it follows that:
$$2^{k+1}>2\cdot (k+1).$$

The rest of the proof is as follows:
$$ =2k+2$$
$$ = k+2+\underbrace{k}_{\geq2} $$
$$ > k+2 $$
$$ = (k+1) +1$$

Where does the $k$ come from in the second line?

Comment: You have $2k$ on the first line, which is then split into one $k$ in parens and the last $k$.

Comment: Please avoid using images for mathematics

Comment: $k$ is any integer $2\leq k \leq n$

Comment: Dam'n I should really stop studying I cannot follow the most obvious statements...Thanks for your help

Comment: No problem, @Rubus!  Make sure to get some good rest.  Not of us is at our best when study too much and sleep too little!

Comment: Avoid referring to "the second line" when we don't know where you start counting.

Comment: Should I delete the question??

Comment: Do you disagree that $2k+2$ and $(k+2)+k$ are the same thing ?

Comment: No I was just unable to see this obvious fact, and I think most students will not make this error so the question is of not much use for others..

Comment: @Rubus Yes. You absolutely should delete this question because , though unlikely, it is possible that someone else could make the same mistake, and we absolutely do not want them to be able to find your question, which would result in them no longer being confused. That would be the worse case scenario, the proof is trivial and left as an exercise to the moderators...

Comment: How did they get $2^{k+1} = 2(k+1)$, it should be $2^{k+1} > 2(k+1)$ lol.

Comment: True..has been incorrectly converted with the conversion to Latex

Comment: Which "second line" do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit confused on what you wrote, so I will just prove this with how induction usually goes. First, find a base case:
$$4=2^2>2+1=3$$
Now we have to show that $2^k>k+1\implies 2^{k+1}>(k+1)+1=k+2$. Assume $2^k>k+1$, then
$$2^k>k+1\implies 2(2^k)>2(k+1)\implies 2^{k+1}>2k+2>k+2$$
and we are done.